# how to add .mp3 to .webm file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add audio(repeat it until the end of the video) to a .webm file. but getting an error-
code i am using is-

```
   ffmpeg -i 1.webm -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp3 -c copy -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  output.webm
```

error i am getting is-

```
    Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

I have checked other posts before writing this post but those solutions did not work for me.
is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The WebM Container does not support the old MP3 audio codec.

Use Opus instead. You need less than half the bitrate for the same quality. Here I choose 96Kbit/s bitrate which should equal to roughly 200 in MP3. Adjust that param. -mapping_family 0 is required for ffmpeg to use most opus optimizations, [standard -1 will deactivate most of them](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1). Use mapping_family 1 if the input source has more than 2 channels.

```
 ffmpeg -i 1.webm -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp3 -vcodec copy -acodec libopus -mapping_family 0 -b:a 96k -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  output.webm
```

If you really want to use old MP3 you can also just use the .mkv container. MKV nearly supports everything.

```
 ffmpeg -i 1.webm -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp3 -c copy -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  output.mkv
```